# NDSolve mathematica fluid mechanics

Tags: differential-equations, physics

[image: streamlines][image: pressure as a funtion o psi eq 14][image: graph I need to make] I have made Mathematica code for equation 16 from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219887819501391). How can we make these streamlines I attached? I am using `DensityPlot` command but can't get it right and if I have to make plot of dp/dx and x. What changes should I do? I am just replacing q values with x. Is it OK?

```
M == 0.5
\[Alpha] == 0.2
n == 0.5
\[Theta] == 0.5
We == 0.02
\[Epsilon] == 0.1
\[Delta] == 0.0006
h == 1 + \[Epsilon]Cos[2 \[Pi] x]
F == \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(h\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]w \[DifferentialD]y\)\)

sol = NDSolve[{((w^
      '')[y]) D[1 + n (We ((w^
            '')[y]) - 1), {y, 2}] - M^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^2) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(''\),
MultilineFunction->None]\)[y] == 0 , 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(''\),
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0] == 0, w[0] == 0, 
w'[h] == -1 - 2 \[Pi]\[Epsilon]\[Alpha]\[Delta]Cos[2 \[Pi] x], 
w[h] == F}, w[y], {y, 0, h}]
```

Comment: is this an ode or pde? what is $\psi$  a function of? just $y$ ?  then why the book uses partial derivatives?

Comment: It could be better to define hydrodynamic problem as it is, without method of solution described in the book. Then we can solve it with FEM or FDM and compare with method from the book. See update to my answer.

Comment: It is not clear in what coordinates stream plot in Figure 9 has been created.

Comment: For completeness, please give a link to the paper you have taken a screenshot of (apparently, it's from World Scientific).

Comment: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0219887819501391

Comment: I've [edited](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/258562/edit) your post to include it; you should do any additions like that yourself the next time.

Comment: ok i will do it

Comment: @J.M. would you like to help?

Comment: @Michael E2 please help.

Answer (score 6):

We can reproduce equation (16) and numerical solution as follows

```
M = 0.5;
\[Alpha] = 0.2;
n = 0.5;
\[Theta] = 0.5; m = M^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
We = 0.02;
\[Epsilon] = 0.1;
\[Delta] = 0.0006; F = 1; x = 0;
h = 1 + \[Epsilon] Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
eq = {psi''[y] == u[y], 
  D[(1 + n (We u[y] - 1)) u[y], y, y] - m u[y] == 0}; bc = {psi[0] == 
   0, u[0] == 0, 
  psi'[h] == -1 - 2 Pi \[Epsilon] \[Alpha] \[Delta] Cos[2 Pi x], 
  psi[h] == F};
sol = NDSolve[Join[eq, bc], {psi, u}, {y, 0, h}]
```

Visualization of velocity profile $\psi '(y)$

```
Plot[psi'[y] /. sol[[1]], {y, 0, h}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using `Module` we can reproduce Figure 1 from paper cited

```
M = 0.5;
\[Alpha] = 0.2;
n = 0.5;
\[Theta] = 0.5; m = M^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
We = 0.02;
\[Delta] = 0.0006; x = 2/3;
p[eps_, qu_] := Module[{e = eps, q = qu}, h = 1 + e Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
  eq = {psi''[y] == u[y], 
    D[(1 + n (We u[y] - 1)) u[y], y, y] - m u[y] == 0}; 
  bc = {psi[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, 
    psi'[h] == -1 - 2 Pi e \[Alpha] \[Delta] Cos[2 Pi x], 
    psi[h] == q - 1};
  px = NDSolveValue[
    Join[eq, 
     bc], (D[(1 + n (We u[y] - 1)) u[y], y] - m psi'[y]) /. {y -> 
       h/2}, {y, 0, h}]; px]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[p[eps, k], {eps, {.1, .3, .5, .6}}]], {k, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"\[Epsilon] = ", eps}], {eps, {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6}}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> { "Q","\[CapitalDelta]p"}] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 1. To plot stream lines as shown in Figure 9, we can use code

```
e = .7; q = .9; M = 0.5;
\[Alpha] = 0.92;
n = 0.99;
\[Theta] = 0.9; m = M^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
We = 0.0001;
\[Delta] = 0.0006;
p[xe_, ye_] := Module[{x = xe, yc = ye}, h = 1 + e Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
  eq = {psi''[y] == u[y], 
    D[(1 + n (We u[y] - 1)) u[y], y, y] - m u[y] == 0}; 
  bc = {psi[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, 
    psi'[h] == -1 - 2 Pi e \[Alpha] \[Delta] Cos[2 Pi x], 
    psi[h] == q - 1};
  Ps = NDSolveValue[Join[eq, bc], psi, {y, 0, h}, 
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 5,
     PrecisionGoal -> 4]; Ps[yc]]

ContourPlot[p[xe, ye], {xe, -.3, .3}, {ye, 0., 1 + e}, Contours -> 30,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Update 2. We can also solve this problem analytically with using series $\psi =\psi_0+We \psi_1+...$ as in a paper cited. We have

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol0 = DSolve[{D[psi[y], {y, 4}] - k D[psi[y], {y, 2}] == 0, 
   psi[0] == 0, psi''[0] == 0, psi'[h] == f0[x], psi[h] == F0}, 
  psi[y], y];

i = D[(D[psi[y] /. sol0[[1]], {y, 2}])^2, {y, 2}] // Simplify;

sol1 = DSolve[{D[psi[y], {y, 4}] - k D[psi[y], {y, 2}] == i n/(n - 1),
    psi[0] == 0, psi''[0] == 0, psi'[h] == 0, psi[h] == F1}, psi[y], 
  y];
f0[x_] := -1 - 2 Pi e a d Cos[2 Pi x]; h = 1 + e Cos[2 Pi x]; k = 
 M^2 Cos[tet]^2/(1 - n);

Psi0 = psi[y] /. sol0[[1]]; Psi1 = psi[y] /. sol1[[1]];
```

Visualization (Figure 9)

```
{e = .7, a = 0.92, tet = 0.9, M = .5, We = .0005, F0 = .9 - 1, F1 = 0,
   n = 0.99, d = .0006};
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Psi0 + We Psi1], {x, -.3, .3}, {y, 0, 1 + e}, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: thank you.....can you please make this graph I attached.

Comment: Yes, we can make any graph. But can you show expression for pressure as a function of $\psi$?

Comment: I have attached the img where eq 14 is a funtion of pressure.

Comment: can you tell me why you have took F=1?

Comment: there?please reply

Comment: @umar In this model we have $Q=F+1$, where $Q$ is a given parameter. Therefore at $F=1$ we have $Q=2$, and it corresponds to the range $-2\le Q\le 2$ in Figure 1 you show.

Comment: there is no error in code but plot lines are not visible in  mathematica

Comment: @umar What version do you run?

Comment: mathematica 10.4

Comment: @umar I have corrected code. Please, try again.

Comment: thanks alot...how did you take x=2/3?

Comment: @umar `x=2/3` has been taken empirically.

Comment: how can we make these streamlines i attached? I am using densityplot command but cant get it right

Comment: and if i have to make plot of dp/dx and x..what changes should i do? i am just replcing q values with x ..is it ok?

Comment: @umar Could you update your post with all questions, and not asking month by month?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: kindly help me.

Comment: @umar Could you open this paper for me? I have no access to this page https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/epdf/10.1142/S0219887819501391

Comment: I also dont have access. I can mail you if you want. your email?

Comment: @umar Please, sent me a letter on trounev@rogers.com

Comment: Sent it to you.

Comment: the above given code for contourplot of different values of e is not resulting the same as in the article.

Comment: @umar I got the paper, thank you. Actually they solved this equation in a form of series  by $We$ powers.  I can reproduce solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with typos corrected. But there remains a big mistake. You give 2 ODE', namely `w''[y] D[1 + n We (w''[y] - 1), {y, 2}] - M^2 Cos[θ]^2 , w''[y] == 0`  instead of one. Presumably  `w''[y] == 0` is wrong.:

```
M == 0.5
α == 0.2
n == 0.5
θ == 0.5
We == 0.02
ϵ == 0.1
δ == 0.0006
h == 1 + ϵ  Cos[2 π x]
F == \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(h\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(y\)]w \[DifferentialD]y\)\)

sol = NDSolve[{w''[y] D[1 + n  We (w''[y] - 1), {y, 2}] - 
    M^2 Cos[θ]^2  ,
   w''[y] == 0 , 
   w''[0] == 0, w[0] == 0, 
   w'[h] == -1 - 2 π ϵ α δ Cos[2 π x], 
   w[h] == F}, w[y], {y, 0, h}]
```